# Search for newest file and see if file is older than 'X' date

Tags: linux, find, date, time, printf

I am attempting to write a script that will recursively search a directory's sub-directories and do the following:

1. Find the most recent file in that sub-directory
2. Find the date of that most recent file
3. Check if that file is older than X days e.g. (180)
4. If the file is older than X days, output its path to a file called "OLD.txt"
5. If the file is NOT older than X days, output its path to a file called "YOUNG.txt"

Currently this is all I have. I am unsure how to grab the date from the file via the find command do the if/then comparison.

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in /u1/?/*/Maildir/new ;
do FILE=$(find "$d" -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head >> Test.txt)
done
```

Other attempts at the same sort of code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Find files older & younger than X days"
echo "Type the number of X days and hit 'Enter':"
read PERIOD
for d in /u1/?/*/Maildir/new ;
do FILE=$(find "$d" -type f -mtime +$PERIOD -exec ls {} \; >> OLDER.txt)
done
for d in /u1/?/*/Maildir/new ;
do FILE=$(find "$d" -type f -mtime -$PERIOD -exec ls {} \; >> YOUNGER.txt)
done
echo "COMPLETE!"
echo "Check 'OLDER.txt' and 'YOUNGER.txt' files in current directory for output"
```

The problem with the last one, is that it outputs ALL the files, while I need to just find the most RECENT file in the directory, and make sure that the most RECENT file isn't older than X days.

Comment: Would you be willing to give an example as to what you mean? I'm pretty sure I understand; just wanted to verify. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `bash` version.

```
#!/bin/bash
maildir='/u1/?/*/Maildir/new'
DAYS_OLD=180

for d in $maildir ; do
    if [ -d "$d" ] ; then
        FILE="$d/"$(ls "$d" -t1  | head -n 1)
        echo $FILE
        if test $(find "$FILE" -mtime +$DAYS_OLD) ; then
            echo $FILE >> OLDER.txt
        else
            echo $FILE >> YOUNGER.txt
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Genius, thank you so much. This will really help me better understand bash scripting and loops. This works amazingly, I'm just confused by one thing in the script. `if [ -d "$d" ] ; then` What is the **-d**; I'm not familiar with the brackets either. I've just begun working on scripting so, I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: You are asking about `$d` or `$()`?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion but I was asking about the `if [ -d "$d" ] ; then` argument. I know `$d` is the directory variable to loop through, but i'm not sure how `-d` comes into play, or what it is. Thank you for your time and help in this matter once again, much obliged kind sir/madam.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script#59839

Comment: Thanks again kind sir/madam! This is great information. I'm guessing the same syntax can be applied to files? `if [ -f "$f" ] ; then` etc. Once again much obliged.

Answer (score 3):

`bash` is not the best shell for that.

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
period=${1?Period not given}
for d (/u1/?/*/Maildir/new) {
  newest=($d/*(DN.om[1]))
  (($#newest)) || continue

  over=($newest(Nm+$period))
  if (($#over)); then
    ls -ld $newest >> OLDER.txt
  else
    ls -ld $newest >> YOUNGER.txt
  fi
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. I am not familiar with zsh. I will check this out, I greatly appreciate your response. Thank you kind sir or madam.